# Как вставить onclick в echo

Tags: php, javascript, html

Как сделать так, что бы `onclick="$('#exampleModal1').arcticmodal()"` работал в `echo`?

```
echo '
     <ul class="logreg">
    <li><a href="#modal1" class="button7">Регистрация</a></li>
  <li><a href="#exampleModal" id="#example1" onclick="$('#exampleModal1').arcticmodal()" class="button8">Войти</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый день.
Вам надо экранировать кавычки и закрыть одинарную кавычку после `</ul>`

```
echo '
 <ul class="logreg">
  <li><a href="#modal1" class="button7">Регистрация</a></li>
  <li><a href="#exampleModal" id="#example1" 
   onclick="$(\'#exampleModal1\').arcticmodal()" class="button8">Войти</a></li>
</ul>';
```

Но лучше так не делать. Не пишите html в тегах php, разделяйте php и html

```
<?php
 // php код
?>
<!-- html код -->
<?php
 // php код
?>
```

[Тут прочитаете подробности](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php)

p.s.
Пример

```
<?php
  if(тут_условие){
?>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#" onclick="function()">Link</a></li>  
 </ul>
 <script>
   /* тут javascript код*/
 </script>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО тебе, очень сильно помог!